# 2017 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Anime & Manga's [3rd moderator election](https://anime.stackexchange.com/election/3) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderator is:

[image: Dimitri mx]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

Also... Please join me in honoring [Madara Uchiha](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/27/madara-uchiha) and [Toshinou Kyouko](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/1530/toshinou-kyouko) as they lay down their weapons and don the garb of ordinary members after 4 and 2 years of service as moderators here.

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://anime.stackexchange.com/election/3), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/6044267751407616/0).

Comment: Congratulations Dimitri mx. Madara Uchiha and Toshinou Kyouko's work here will be missed and I hope they are doing fine and will be seen around.

Answer (score 16):

Congratulations Dimitri mx - I believe you'll make a fantastic moderator.

Thanks to Madara Uchiha and Toshinou Kyouko for sticking in there as mods.  Your services are appreciated, and while it's unfortunate that you are stepping down, I believe that there are good reasons for such.  Thanks again for your efforts here.

Answer (score 8):

Congratulations Dimitri, I know you'll do a fine job.

Thanks for giving the chance to be a mod at this amazing community. It's been tough making the decision but I know I'm leaving the site in better hands.

Take care, and I'll be right next door ;)

Comment: Mod Release Technique?