# 2020 Potential Community Moderator Election - Community Interest Check

Tags: discussion, election

**Thanks for the interest, folks. We've now set a date for the election to start question collection next Monday, October 12th, 2020. Nominations will open the following week in the [4th moderator election](https://anime.stackexchange.com/election/4).**

---

It's time for us all to consider holding an election for a new volunteer moderator on A&M.

The last election we have held was [back in 2017](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4089/2017-community-moderator-election-results), at which point I joined the moderator team.
Ever since the [Moderator Questionare](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4080/1458) of that year, I wanted to see if we could diversify our community. And very recently [кяαzєя♦](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/users/63/%d0%ba%d1%8f%ce%b1z%d1%94%d1%8f) and I started the chain of monthly engagement posts, in part to see if we could achieve just that some how.
Hence we could use another set of hands to help us with moderation, and improving the community.

In the end, it's not a lot of work to being a moderator, and this is a relatively small SE site

You can also take a look at [Who are the site moderators, and what is their role here?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/help/site-moderators) and the [Theory of moderation (revisited)](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) to get a bit of a feeling as to what being a moderator actually entails.

**Please leave an answer if you'd be willing to run for a moderator position, should we decide to run an election.**

NOTE: This is not an official election nomination thread, just a "pulse check" to get a notion of how many people here would be willing to step up.

Comment: Since this is a pulse is there like a minimum activity bar? Say only one person answers then no election will be held?

Comment: Since we'd be aiming for a single-slot election, we'd need at least 2 candidates for the election to not fail. As such, I think at least 2 people demonstrating interest here is likely enough to go ahead with the election — if we have just one, though, the CM and moderator teams will discuss whether we wanna push forward with an election that might fail, or if we wanna wait for a bit longer.

Answer (score 9):

Just to start the ball rolling, **I'm interested in running as a moderator on Anime.SE.**

While I'm already a moderator on Android.SE, there's really nothing much to handle with the current mod team on there (just a daily NAA and explicit off-topic questions clean-up, nuking a handful of spam, etc...), and I'm still able to put some time to visit Anime.SE daily to check almost all of the new posts.

However, *I'm also encouraging other users who haven't already been a mod on any SE site to join this mod team and taste the experience* :)

Comment: Hullo! Just a gentle reminder that [nominations are now open](https://anime.stackexchange.com/election), in case you missed it ^_^

Answer (score 7):

Following Aki Tanaka's encouragement, I too am interested as running for a moderator on Anime SE.

Arqade SE, the site I am primarily active on, held a moderator election last year. I considered participating in the election, but the responsibilities would have been too much for me to handle at the moment in time. Since Anime SE is smaller, I would like to put my name into the hat as a future moderator

Comment: Hullo! Just a gentle reminder that [nominations are now open](https://anime.stackexchange.com/election), in case you missed it ^_^

Comment: @JNat Thanks for the reminder! I am working on my last two answers, and should have my submissions posted today or tomorrow :)

Comment: No worries or pressure at all; just wanted to make sure you hadn't missed it :)